# LINQ сумма в итогах

Tags: c#, linq, uwp

Здравствуйте!

UWP. Пытаюсь сделать группированный список с помощью CollectionViewSource.
Надо сделать так, чтобы в группировках отображалась итоговая сумма по группировке.
Помогите, пожалуйста, изменить запрос, чтобы в итоговых строках были итоговые суммы:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Store> storeList = new List<Store>();
    storeList.Add(new Store(){Name = "Склад", StoreType = "Type1", Quantity = 100});
    storeList.Add(new Store(){Name = "Склад 2", StoreType = "Type1", Quantity = 200});
    storeList.Add(new Store(){Name = "Склад 3", StoreType = "Type2", Quantity = 150});

   var result = from act in storeList group act by act.StoreType into grp orderby grp.Key select grp;

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key,-15}");

        foreach (var item2 in item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key,25}");            
        }
    }

    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit");
}

public class Store
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string StoreType { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

Вот примерно так надо бы:
[image: Пример]![https://clip2net.com/s/3Sx3Hfv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать что то подобное:

```
var categoryCounts =
    from s in storeList
    group s by s.StoreType into g
    select new { Category = g.Key, StoreCount = g.Sum(c=>c.Quantity), Items = g.ToList()};
```

То есть мы берем нашу коллекцию, в ней группируем по `StoreType`, затем формируем все в удобном для нас виде, где выводим имя группы, общую сумму, а также элементы, которые в нашей группе.

---

Повозился с выводом (в новинку для меня это позиционирование текста) и добился нужного результата:

```
foreach (var group in categoryCounts)
{
    Console.Write($"{group.Category,-15}");
    Console.Write($"{group.StoreCount,15}");
    foreach (var item in group.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write($"{item.StoreType,15}");
        Console.Write($"{item.Quantity,15}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

На выходе:

```
Type1                      300
          Type1            100
          Type1            200
Type2                      150
          Type2            150
```

Comment: к сожалению, в этом случае в списке ListView показываются только заголовки, без детальных данных.
[https://clip2net.com/s/3SxtFt9]
Есть ещё варианты, как сделать изначальный результат, только с итоговыми суммами?

Comment: @Zixi А как у вас ДО этого отображалось все? И можно увидеть разметку ListView, а не ресурсы. P.S. Для дополнения ответа есть кнопка редактирования, не пишите доп. данные для вопроса в виде ответа!

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код разметки:

```
<Page.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="StoreTypeOfCollection"
        Source="{x:Bind MyStoreList}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="MyStoreList.Items"/>


        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvsActivities" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
        <local:ListGroupStyleSelector x:Key="listGroupStyleSelector"/>


    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <StackPanel>

            <ListView x:Name="MyList2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsActivities}}" 

                     GroupStyleSelector="{StaticResource listGroupStyleSelector}"
                      Header = "Мой список 3" Margin="79,50,5,5"  Height="300" Width="750" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Store" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=StoreType}" Grid.Column="1" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Quantity}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

Результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И вот никак сумму в итоги добавить не получается.
Или список без итогов сумм или наоборот - только итоги без списка.
Засада какая-то.... Хелп!

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо @EvgeniyZ !

Ваш запрос - отлично подошёл!

Просто мне надо было указать правильный путь к детальным записям:  ItemsPath="Items"

```
   <Page.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvsActivities" IsSourceGrouped="True" ItemsPath="Items"/>
        <local:ListGroupStyleSelector x:Key="listGroupStyleSelector"/>

   </Page.Resources>
```

Сделал так - и всё заработало.
Ура! Большое спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]